# P-Channel MOSFET to delay full power

Tags: mosfet, delay

I am new to electronics so please bear with me!  I tried searching for help on this one, a lot of useful info on reverse polarity but I couldn't find much on this situation.

I am using a DC-DC converter that supplies 12 V and 30 A.  The DC-DC converter has a soft start, whereby it ramps up from 0 V to 12 V over some time, when the system is turned on.  During this ramp up, the system cannot draw more than 2.66 A until the DC-DC converter reaches 6 V.

I initially thought of using a time delay relay, of say 1 second, to ensure that the system started correctly.  However, I then thought I could use a P-Channel MOSFET as it looks to be a more elegant solution.

The idea of have is shown in Image 1.  The idea was that the MOSFET would conduct less than 2.66 A until 6 V is reached.  The problem I have is that I cannot find a MOSFET with a high enough gate to source threshold and low enough resistance, as at 30 Amps the resistance needs to be as low as possible.

I can only find high Rds, high Vgs(th) or low Rds, low Vgs(th) MOSFETs.  I can't find a suitable Rds high Vgs(th).

I therefore thought I could add a resistor to the circuit as shown in Image 2 to a low Rds, low Vgs(th) MOSFET.  The thought being that this resistor would also take some voltage, thereby effectively increasing the Vgs(th).  The problem is I don't have sufficient knowledge to know whether this would work, or the equations involved.

[image: schematics]

Comment: Using a PMOS may not be a solution since the body diode (seen between D and S in the images) conducts initially. By the way, `this resistor would also take some voltage, thereby effectively increasing the Vgs(th)` is not correct, because practically the gate does not draw current *(or draws in pA range)*. That resistor may effectively bring a delay in conjunction with the Ciss of the MOSFET.

Comment: It may flat out be challenging to find a PMOS that can pass 30A without a heatsink. So how much is this worth to you to add this feature? NMOS may be another option, but high-side NMOS requires a special driver.

Comment: Thanks Rohat, i've since learnt a lot more about the PMOS, if I was to do what I was suggesting I'd need two resistors, one from the + rail to the gate and one from the gate the ground, however as you pointed out the diode will conduct.

Comment: Good point mkeith, luckily I have a large heatsink, but as you pointed out is it worth it

Answer (score 6):

Vgsth is too variable from part to part, and the response of the FET to soft to the gate voltage around Vgsth, that you should split your circuit into a sense part, and a power part.

Use a proper comparator in the sense part.

Use a power FET in the powe part, that gets switched by the comparator.

More complicated I know, but you can make it work to your specifications.

Comment: Thanks Neil, I've investigate splitting it into sense and power part

Answer (score 2):

Use a power mosfet with low rds on to pass the source voltage to the load. Then use discrete transistors to turn the pass fet either on or off.

I would recommend putting the timing into the discrete control circuit.
See this link for some common issues and applications.
https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9093-D.PDF

Comment: Great link thanks Jdlachenmyer, this is exactly the kind of information I'm after

Answer (score 0):

That can work to limit the rise time.  Because you're not using the transistor to switch on and off, you need 3 things:

1. You have to swap the source and drain of the FET so that it won't
   conduct through the body diode.
2. You have to put a capacitor between drain and gate.  The size of this cap will, with the gate resistor, determine the rise time.
3. You have to put a larger capacitor (about 10X) from source to gate.  This initializes the circuit by keeping Vgs from going full on when you first apply power.

It doesn't limit current, as such, but limits the rise speed of the load voltage.  If you're only worried about a time delay, you can eliminate the gate-drain cap.

Comment: Thanks Cristobol, this is a good option as it sounds like it would require few components